# bcrypt compare: callback not triggered

Tags: javascript, react-native, bcrypt

I'm having a strange issue with **bcrypt.compare()**.

Check this:

```
function logUserIn(redirectRouteName) {
    setIsLogin(true);
    const fields = User.getPropertiesName();
    Base('Customers').select({
      maxRecords: 1,
      fields,
      filterByFormula: `email = "${state.username}"`
    }).eachPage((records, fetchNextPage) => {
      const user = new User(records[0].fields);
      bcrypt.setRandomFallback((len) => {
        const buf = new Uint8Array(len);
        return buf.map(() => Math.floor(isaac.random() * 256));
      });

      bcrypt.compare(state.password, user.password, (err, res) => {
        // console.log('hello'): returns nothing...
        if(res){
          setUserData(user);
          setIsLogin(false);
          props.navigation.navigate(redirectRouteName);
        }
      });

    }, (err) => {
      if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    });

  }
```

My issue is, bcrypt compare callback is not triggered. I put logs around it, it's fine, `state.password` and `user.password` do contains the expected values. In fact nothing in bcrypt.compare is exectued, so... I'm lost here. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the `eachPage` callback runs? Make there's no user records at all.

Comment: Yes it does. I can log user data just before running bcrypt compare, and it does contain the expected values.

Comment: Are `.setRandomFallback` and `.compare` methods executing in the expected order? Inside `.compare`callback, can you log `err` and `res`?

Comment: No I can't. Actually, after 1 hour debugging, it turns out `props.navigation.navigate(redirectRouteName);` was failing silently, breaking all the logs in the callback...